# What is the difference between "doing something" and "on doing something"?

Tags: verbs, differences

I don't understand the difference between "doing something" and "on doing something". I am going to make up a few examples.

(1) On cleaning up my bedroom, I found my valuable watch.

(2) Cleaning up my bedroom, I found my valuable watch.

Do these sentences have the same meaning? Please explain it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

They don't have the same meaning at all.

1. The preposition *on* is used as a function word to **indicate an *instant* when something begins or is done** according to [Merriam Webster definition No. 3](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on). Therefore, No. (1) sentence could be rephrased to

> As soon as (The moment) I started to clean up my bedroom, I found
>   my valuable watch.

2. No. (2) sentence could be rephrased to

> When I Cleaned up my bedroom / While I was cleaning up my bedroom, I found my valuable watch.

"Cleaning up my bedroom" is called [*participle clause*](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/participle-clauses) or [*absolute clause (construction)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction). You can visit the links and see how they work.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same meaning, I'd say. Both have implied additional words:

[Upon] ... cleaning up my bedroom, I found my valuable watch.
or
On [the occasion of] cleaning up my bedroom, I found my valuable watch.

[While] [c]leaning up my bedroom, I found my valuable watch.

Comment: "upon" means "immediately after finishing cleaning", as opposed to "while" which means "during my cleaning"